# Set value of multidimensional array into key of new array using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having this array

```
array (
    0 => array ( 'sno' => 'q3', 'result' => '15', ),
    1 => array ( 'sno' => 'q1', 'result' => '5', ),
    2 => array ( 'sno' => 'q2', 'result' => '10', ),
)
```

i want this resulting array

```
array ( 
    'q3' => '15', 
    'q1' => '5',
    'q2' =>'10' 
)
```

if possible without using any loop?
if Yes Then How?

Comment: What have you tried? Take a look at the list of [PHP array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Comment: [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) is the function you're looking for

Comment: I have use forech loop

Comment: Answer it @MarkBaker

Comment: Finally Got the Solution Thank's @Mark Baker

Comment: array_column($array, 'result', 'sno');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is your input array,**

```
$arr=  array (
    0 => array ( 'sno' => 'q3', 'result' => '15', ),
    1 => array ( 'sno' => 'q1', 'result' => '5', ),
    2 => array ( 'sno' => 'q2', 'result' => '10', ),
);
```

**Here is one liner code :**

```
$result = array_combine(array_column($arr, 'sno'), array_column($arr, 'result'));  
// $result = array_column($arr,'result','sno');
```

**What I am doing is**

1. [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) will fetch all values in array related to specific key, so I fetched two arrays values to specific keys
2. Then I used [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to create an array by using one array for keys and another for its values.

**Here is output:**

```
Array
(
    [q3] => 15
    [q1] => 5
    [q2] => 10
)
```

**Here is working code**

[click here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/418ef0885e6d5906677487ad1008ebdea7dea472)

Answer (score 0):

Using [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) you can create new array contain custom key/value from an array.

```
$newArr = array_reduce($oldArr, function($carry, $item){
    $carry[$item["sno"]] = $item["result"];
    return $carry;
});
```

Check code result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/0aoTF)